# Undefined property error with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I keep getting this same error, no matter what I try;

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$description
```

Here is my code in my Controller;

```
$gorDistinct = PostcodeExtract::fromTable($tableName)
                ->distinct()
                ->select('gor')
                ->get();

    foreach($gorDistinct as $key => $value)
    {
        print $value->gor;

        $descGorLookup = GorLookup::select('description')
              ->where('oldcode', '=', $value->gor)
              ->get();

        print $descGorLookup->description;
        print "<br>";

        exit;
    }
```

This is currently my GorLookup Model;

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

   class GorLookup extends Model {

   protected $connection = 'postcodes';
   protected $table = 'pc_gor_030315';
   protected $fillable = array('description', 'oldcode');
 }
```

I understand that this does not make best use of the Relationships feature of Laravel. For now I just need to get this part working!

Comment: it's returning array instead get you should use first() to echo description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get Return result as object array you can use first to get description.

replace get() with first()

```
$descGorLookup = GorLookup::select('description')
                           ->where('oldcode', '=', $value->gor)
                           ->first(); // change here
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$gorDistinct = PostcodeExtract::fromTable($tableName)
    ->distinct()
    ->select('gor')
    ->first();

foreach($gorDistinct as $key => $value)
{
    print $value->gor;

    $descGorLookup = GorLookup::select('description')
          ->where('oldcode', '=', $value->gor)
          ->first();

    print $descGorLookup->description;
    print "<br>";

    exit;
}
```